# UDP Tx loop stops working every time at exactly 3970 packets, 14386 on my friends computer

Tags: c++, c, sockets, udp, packets

I've been stuck at this issue for the last 4 days and I can't seem to figure it out. I'm trying to send data to myself using UDP packets so another program can read the bytes.

I can clearly read the packets but I only get up to 3970 before the UDP portion of the program hangs. Glut and everything else continues to run fine. I gave my friend the same code and he ran it on his computer. He got 14386 iterations before it hangs. variable temp will count the number of packets sent. -1 is bad. counter counts the while loop iterations. I'm following the example here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740148(v=vs.85).aspx

Example Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <WinSock2.h> // don't forget to add in 
//Project Properties>Linker>Input>Additional Dependences [Ws2_32.lib]
sockaddr_in dest;
sockaddr_in local;
WSAData data;
static void SUDP_init(void)
{
    printf("--[UDP Socket Initialized]--\r\n");
    WSAStartup( MAKEWORD( 2, 2 ), &data );

    local.sin_family = AF_INET;
    local.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "127.0.0.1" ); //same as localhost
    local.sin_port = 6000;

    dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dest.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "127.0.0.1" );
    dest.sin_port = htons( 6000 );

    bind( socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0 ), (sockaddr *)&local, sizeof(local) );
    printf("Socket Bound...\r\n");
}
static int counter = 0;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    SUDP_init();
    while(1){
        char packet[30];
        sprintf(packet, "%0.3f,%0.3f,%0.3f", 
        55.4,
        16.1,
        -27.88);

        int temp = sendto( socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0 ), packet, strlen(packet), 0, (sockaddr *)&dest, sizeof(dest) );
        if(temp>=1){
            counter++;
        }
        printf("Bytes Sent: %d, Counter: %d\r\n",temp,counter);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are allocating new sockets in a loop (the first argument to `sendto`), you are also allocating another for `bind`, but these are never freed. You eventually run out of socket handles to allocate, hence your program hanging.

Instead, allocate a socket once in `SUDP_init`, store it instead of discarding it, then pass that to `bind` and `sendto`

Comment: I do not know how to thank you enough! I should've followed the the instructions to the letter and read more. The devil is in the details.

Comment: And the reason that you run out of sockets at around 4000 is that the default value for `MAXUSERPORT` is 5000 and some sockets are used by system services. (see here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938196.aspx and here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/tristank/archive/2008/03/11/maxuserport-what-it-is-what-it-does-when-it-s-important.aspx)